# automapper configuration to automatically map entity to same entity

Tags: automapper

Is there a way to configure AutoMapper to make it automatically map an entity to itself...

I want to avoid this basically:

```cs
    Mapper.CreateMap<Company, Company>();
    Mapper.CreateMap<Car, Car>();
....
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [DynamicMap](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/04/15/automapper-feature-interfaces-and-dynamic-mapping), without configuring CreateMap:

```cs
var companyMapped = Mapper.DynamicMap<Company>(company);
```

> The DynamicMap call creates a configuration for the type of the source
>   object passed in to the destination type specified.  If the two types
>   have already been mapped, AutoMapper skips this step (as I can call
>   DynamicMap multiple times for this example).  To be safe, AutoMapper
>   will validate the configuration for a dynamic map the first time
>   executed, as it tends to give better messages than a mapping
>   exception.
>
> With DynamicMap, you don’t have the luxury of configuring the mapping,
>   but at this point, you’ve also lost the benefits of a single
>   AssertConfigurationIsValid call.  In the DynamicMap side, I could
>   lower the bar quite a bit and not do any mapping validation, but I’d
>   rather not as its intended use is a very specific scenario.  The ideal
>   case is to configure your mappings up front, for much better
>   testability.